# RFID конвертирование?

Tags: hex

Два считывателя. Читают по разному одни и те же ключи. Как привести к общему значению между ними? (какой алгоритм)

Примеры:

```
знач считывателя #1 = знач считывателя #2
-----------------------------------------
ключ 1) 0010670272 = 3f00a2d0c0;
ключ 2) 0035095307 = 280217830b;
ключ 3) 1521149537 = 565aaae661;
ключ 4) 1518434594 = 565a817922;
```

Comment: А что говорит техническая документация на считыватели по поводу возвращаемого считывателем значения?

Comment: Китаец. Нет на него документации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считыватель 1 возвращает десятичное значение, считыватель 2 шестнадцатиричное.

Для конвертации преобразуйте оба в двоичные и отбросьте 8 (?) ведущих битов у кода, полученного со считывателя 2. Остатки идентичны (с точностью до ведущих нулей):

```
0010670272                 101000101101000011000000
3f00a2d0c0 0011111100000000101000101101000011000000

1518434594          1011010100000010111100100100010          
565a817922 0101011001011010100000010111100100100010
```

**UPD:**

Для сравнения показаний второго прибора c показаниями первого в Excel используйте следующий макрос (поместить в common-модуль, использовать при написании формул):

```
Public Function Hex32_to_Dec(HexVal) As Long
    Hex32_to_Dec = "&H" & Right(Trim(CStr(HexVal)), 8)
End Function
```

Comment: Нашел Эксель-файлик, по формулам разобрал следующее: сумма каждого символа HEX в DEC (без первых 2х) помноженное на 10ый на 1, 9ый на 16, 8ой на 256.   Намудрено)

Comment: @dnikitin добавил макрос для Excel.